# Controlar cierre inesperado proceso Java

Tags: java, mysql

Tengo una aplicación diseñada en `Java` la cual tiene conexión a `MySQL`. Quisiera controlar el **inicio de sesión** de los administradores de la app.

- Cuando inicie sesión el administrador, cambie el "**estado**" a valor = 1.
- Cuando salga de la sesión, cambie el "**estado**" a valor = 0.

El valor de "estado" lo guardo en `SQL` como si se tratara de un `booleano` (en `SQL` al no existir el tipo de dato `boolean`, le asigno `bit`).

Tengo los siguientes métodos para el control del estado (si está conectado o no).

```
   public static int ver_estado(String administrador) {
        String bbdd = Conexiones.bbdd;
        Connection c = (Connection) Conexiones.conexion_a_BBDD(bbdd);
        Statement stm;
        ResultSet rs;
        int estado = 0;
        try {
            stm = c.createStatement();
            String consulta_de_un_administrador = "SELECT a.estado FROM administradores AS a WHERE a.administrador='" + administrador + "';";
            rs = stm.executeQuery(consulta_de_un_administrador);
            rs.next();
            estado = rs.getInt("estado");
            c.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("El estado de "+administrador+" es: "+estado);
        return estado;
    }
```

Si me logueo en la aplicación correctamente, **actualizo el valor estado a 1.**

```
   public static void activar_estado(String administrador) {
        String bbdd = Conexiones.bbdd;
        Connection c = (Connection) Conexiones.conexion_a_BBDD(bbdd);
        try (PreparedStatement stm = c.prepareStatement("UPDATE administradores SET estado=1 WHERE administrador = ?")) {
            stm.setString(1, administrador);
            int resultado1 = 1;
            resultado1 = stm.executeUpdate();
            if (resultado1 <= 0) {
                throw new SQLException();
            } else {
                //System.out.println("Activado el estado del administrador correctamente.");
            }
            c.setAutoCommit(false);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                c.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Lo mismo, si me desconecto llamo a desactivar_estado(String administrador) cambiando a 0.

**¿Qué pasa si estoy logueado (estado=1) y se cierra el proceso de la aplicación de forma repentina inesperadamente?**

**He cerrado el proceso de Java / Netbeans** para ver qué sucedería y no vuelve al valor estado=0, ¿cómo podría controlarlo?

Comment: Podrías tomar un enfoque diferente y usar un campo de fecha  que cada cierto tiempo se esté actualizando mientras el usuario esté en la aplicación. Así si el proceso finaliza se puede deducir según la última fecha si el usuario está o no en la aplicación.

Comment: La aplicacion permite que si el usuario ya esta loguado pueda volverse a loguear?

Comment: @Japv Si hay un usuario ya logueado en la aplicación e inicio otra instancia de la aplicación para intentar loguearme con ese mismo usuario me dice que el usuario ya está logueado y no me permite realizar la operación hasta que cierre sesión en el ya conectado. Eso me funciona. ¿Pero cómo puedo controlar si se cierra el proceso de Java?

Comment: Ahi es donde esta el problema, ya que si lo haces como lo tienes hecho hasta ahora, si ocurriese un error inesperado mientras el usuario estaba logueado, pues no va a poder loguearse nuevamente ya que su cuenta quedo como activa, valora cambiar esto, imagina que eso pasara con Facebook por ejemplo (tendrias que crearte una cuenta nueva si ocurriese un corte electrico), en Facebook tu puedes loguearte n-veces, y yo en lo particular defiendo esa filosofia, ya que evita ese problema que tienes

Comment: @Japv Gracias por la explicación. La deducción (teoría) la entendí... pero mi problema es llevarlo a la práctica. No sé que camino tomar para poder resolverlo. Hay alguna opción para comprobar que "crashea" el programa insesperadamente para reestablecer el valor de estado a 0 (teniendo el 1 si está logueado).

Comment: No lo hagas asi, esa validacion sobra, con no hacerlo reesuelves el problema y ya

Comment: @Japv ¿Con no hacer la validación lo resuelvo? ¿Entonces cómo controlo que no se pueda loguear 2 veces con el mismo usuario a la vez?

Comment: Es que eso no tienes que controlarlo, eso no es un problema, entiende que no esta mal que el usuario pueda loguearse dos veces, lo que si debes hacer es un mecanismo que guarde las trazas para ver precisamente que hace cada usuario en el sistema

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133993/discussion-between-omaza1990-and-japv).

Comment: Permitir que un usuario loguee dos veces no es tan sencillo como propones, @Japv. Si no mantienes ambas sesiones perfectamente sincronizadas acabarás teniendo problemas de sincronismo entre los datos de ambas sesiones y puede dar problemas si por ejemplo intentas editar un objeto que ya no existe porque se te olvidó refrescar el contenido en la sesión anterior que mantuviste abierta.